# MVC JQuery Loads Too Quickly

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog, partial-views

I am using MVC3 and Entity Framework.  I have a List on a page with checkboxes for the user to select multiple items.  (The goal is to "Reassign" multiples at a time).

When the user clicks the "Reassign" buttion it invokes a JQuery Dialog box to appear and it loads the partial view.  On the partial view, I have a hidden field for the checkboxes that were selected.

**An example would be:**

```
<input type="hidden" value="2,4,5" class="tasks" name="tasks" />
```

However, my code runs too fast for the JQuery to grab which checkboxes were checked.  When I view the Dialog box HTML in Firebug, the value is empty.

I have tested my code out by doing:

```
    var checkeditems = $('input:checkbox[name="selectedObjects"]:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val() }).get().join(",");
    alert(checkeditems);
    $('input.tasks').val(checkeditems);
```

Weirdly, the values are put into the hidden field. Without the alert, they are not there.

**Here is my Javascript:**

```
$('#ReAssign').bind('click', function (event, ui) {
    GetReassign();
    return false;
});

function GetReassign() {
    $("#ReassignDialog").dialog({
        height: 315,
        width: 525,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).load('/InterviewFollowup/ReassignPartial');
        },
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    var checkeditems = $('input:checkbox[name="selectedObjects"]:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val() }).get().join(",");
    $('input.tasks').val(checkeditems);
}
```

**Here is my View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ReassignPost","InterviewFollowup")) {
<fieldset>
    <legend><strong>Re-Assign Task</strong></legend>

    <input type="hidden" value="" id="tasks" class="tasks" name="tasks" />

    <div class="editor-label">
        Location:
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("MailCodes", (SelectList)ViewBag.MailCodes,"-- Select --")
        @Html.ValidationMessage("MailCodes") 
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssignedTo)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <select name="AssignedTo" id="AssignedTo"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        Notes:
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="text" name="Notes" id="Notes" />
        @Html.ValidationMessage("Notes") 
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" />
    </p>

</fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.load()` jQuery function is asynchronous (it's an AJAX call), so this code:

```
var checkeditems = $('input:checkbox[name="selectedObjects"]:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val() }).get().join(",");
$('input.tasks').val(checkeditems);
```

is run before the partial view has been loaded, and therefore your `$('input.tasks')` selector doesn't match an element - adding the alert fixes this because it delays execution of the next line until **after** the AJAX call has completed. You'll want to move that code into a callback function for when the `.load()` has completed, like so:

```
$(this).load('/InterviewFollowup/ReassignPartial', function() {
    var checkeditems = $('input:checkbox[name="selectedObjects"]:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val() }).get().join(",");
    $('input.tasks').val(checkeditems);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are accessing some DOM elements before it finishes loading. I would wrap your code 
in document ready

```
$(function(){

   $('#ReAssign').bind('click', function (event, ui) {
       GetReassign();
      return false;
   });

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

[http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

**From the above page**,

> This is the first thing to learn about jQuery: If you want an event to
>   work on your page, you should call it inside the $(document).ready()
>   function. Everything inside it will load as soon as the DOM is loaded
>   and before the page contents are loaded.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't provide the entire code in my JS.  I do have "$(document).ready(function () {" at the start of my JS file.